# Animate highcharts bubble graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, bubble-chart

I have a chart which shows the growth, share and revenue of a product in a bubble graph. 
I build this chart for every year since 2006. Now my question is if I can animate the chart from year to year so that you can see the changes.

I already tried to something with ajax and json. It shows the new data but it won't animate.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'json.php', 
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data && data != ''){
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                portfolioChart.series[i].setData([[ data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2] ]]);

                                portfolioChart.redraw();
                            }                               
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(html){alert(html)},
                    data: {year: act_year}
                });
```

There are about 5 - 15 products to be loaded (animated)

**UPDATE**

Now it's working quite well. The main problem is the number of products. Up to 4-5 products it works smooth.
Here's my final code:

```
var years = [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015];

$.each(years, function(pi, act_year){

    setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: 'json.php', 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data && data != ''){
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        portfolioChart.series[i].setData([[ data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2] ]]);
                    }           
                }
            },
            error: function(html){alert(html)},
            data: {year: act_year, products: productArray}
        });
    }, 500 + ( pi * 2000 ));
});
```

Comment: It should animate properly when you have exactly the same number of points in `setData(points)`. Also, call `setData(points, false, false)`. That will prevent from running animation multiple times. Then call `chart.redraw()`. Like this: `for( ... ) { ... } chart.redraw()`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works very smooth